# Wordpress Theme Nouice with comments?

Tags: wordpress, templates, comments

I am using this theme for my wordpress blog
http://www.bestwpthemes.com/nouice/
, however it was not until I did quite a bit of customization that I realized it has no comments build-in.

I am just wondering is there a version of it that does have comments? I tried to use both suggestions listed on this page:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/autofocus-theme-comments-in-pages

But has no luck...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme comes with a comments.php template file, but it doesn't use it anywhere! Very strange indeed! I guess the author meant the template as a CMS and so forgot about including the comments file.

Anyway, it is straight forward to include the comments template file wherever you need to, I guess this will be the single.php template (so comments appear whenever you are accessing a single post) and the page.php template (for pages obviously).

For the single.php file, you can change line 20 to include the comments:

```
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

</div><!-- end .post -->
```

And the same on page.php, around line 15. I tried it and works fine:

[image]

Comment: Hello AJweb, Thanks for the quick response, however for some reason although I can get the comment box to show up, I could not see the actual comments displayed even after I entered them...any clue why that is the case?

Comment: I have tried both add comments as admin as well as just as a random user, the comments just don't show up :(

Comment: @zhuanyi, you are right, I included the comments template the wrong way, I edited my answer with the correct: `comments_template();` call.